# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `SELECT` with a `GROUP_CONCAT` column as follows:

```
SELECT
    m.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(s.id ORDER BY s.id ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS schedule_ids

FROM months m

LEFT JOIN schedule s
    ON (MONTH(s.start_date) = m.id) OR (MONTH(s.end_date) = m.id)

GROUP BY m.id
```

This column currently returns a comma separated string of 2 IDs, eg: `1, 2` or `11, 12`.

I want to add an `IF` condition to the `ORDER BY`, whereby in the specific instance where the IDs returned are `1, 12`, the ORDER BY should be `DESC`, i.e. it should return `12, 1`, otherwise keep it as `ASC`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is your very specific condition, then I would suggest a `CASE` expression:

```
(CASE WHEN GROUP_CONCAT(s.id ORDER BY s.id ASC SEPARATOR ', ') = '1, 12'
      THEN '12, 1'
      ELSE GROUP_CONCAT(s.id ORDER BY s.id ASC SEPARATOR ', ') 
 END)
```